# Intellij IDEA и java компилятор

Tags: java

Получается, когда мы работаем в IDEA, то компилятор, будем говорить, отрабатывает еще в процессе написания кода, так?
А когда мы запускаем код, что отлавливает ошибки? jvm?
Пожалуйста, подскажите

Comment: `компилятор, будем говорить, отрабатывает еще в процессе написания кода, так?` - нет, компилятор собирает jar перед тем как его запустить, сразу же покажет ошибки, которые не дают собрать jar. JVM отлавливает ошибки времени выполнения. Во время написания кода ошибки находит и показывает IDE.

Comment: @insolor компилятор **компилирует** код. Собирает проект `ant`, `maven`, `gradle`

Comment: @notaProgrammer, компилятор javac компилирует исходный код в классы, потом собирает их в jar. Инструменты сборки - это уже надстройка, которая вызывает другие инструменты (тот же javac). Никто не мешает собирать проект вручную, запуская команды в терминале без всяких инструментов сборки, при этом это все равно будет сборкой проекта.

Comment: @insolor вы правы))

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете фичу *Code Inspection* с компиляцией.

[Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) - это некий фоновый процесс (его можно отключить), который в фоновом режиме сканирует и проверяет качество кода. Инспекцию можно настроить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компиляция в отличие от инспекции - это уже окончательный вердикт и проводится не средствами IDE, а компилятором. Компилятор проверяет только синтаксис, но не качество кода, скажем типичный пример, если инспектор может "ругаться", на неиспользуемую переменную, то компилятору в общем то все равно.